# Call CSS from public folder on view. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, css, view, laravel-5.3

Good afternoon, im trying to call css from a view file ( create.blade.php ) 
I've been trying a lot of methods, like calling:

**{{ HTML::style('css.section') }}**

And the results are always the same, HTML class not found. (i installed it but is an old version)
Or the view is the default from bootstrap style.
I just want a clean code, because is pretty nasty to have a 
style tag inside a form.

This is my CSS. from "public/css/section.css"

```
<style>
    section {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        background-size: 2000px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        float: none;
    }
</style>
```

And this is one of my many views, where you can see how bad the style tags looks:

```
@extends('admin.template.main')

@section('title' , 'Listado de negocios')

@section('content')

<style>
    section {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        background-size: 2000px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        float: none;
        }
</style>

    <a href="{{ route('admin.stores.create') }}" class="btn btn-info">Agregar negocio</a><hr>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Icono</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Accion</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($stores as $store)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $store->id }}</td>
                    <td><img class="thumbnail" src="/icon/stores/{{$store->id}}/{{ $store->icon }}" width="200" height="150"></td>
                    <td>{{ $store->name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.stores.destroy', $store->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="return confirm('Seguro que deseas eliminar este negocio?')" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.stores.edit', $store->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

@endsection
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: no need of including `<style>` tag inside your CSS file.

Comment: What a dumb mistake, thankyou @nmnsud !

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML` class has been removed from the Illuminate package in Laravel framework > version 5.

To make it work, you could do this:

Add this in your **composer.json**

```
"illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

and run

```
composer update
```

Under providers array in **app.php**, add this line

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and add these under alias array:

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Now you're ready to use HTML class in your blade views like this.

```
{!! HTML::style('assets/css/css.section.css') !!}
```

Hope this helps!